# selenium doesn't see the cookies button python

Tags: python, selenium

```
  root = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#usercentrics-root")
  print("1")
  shadow_root = self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", root)
  elem = shadow_root.find_element(
       By.CSS_SELECTOR,
        "#uc-center-container > div.sc-bYoBSM.egarKh > div > div.sc-dlVxhl.ezVnxI > div > div > button.sc-gsDKAQ.jiHobE",)
  elem.click()
```

I wrote the code as above, but it never sees the button and the code explodes in elem=...
I wrote the code as above, but it never sees the button and the code explodes in elem=...
I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: is url is public please share.

Answer (score 0):

Use try_except block to handle that.

```
try:

  root = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#usercentrics-root")
  print("1")
  shadow_root = self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", root)
  elem = shadow_root.find_element(
       By.CSS_SELECTOR,
        "#uc-center-container > div.sc-bYoBSM.egarKh > div > div.sc-dlVxhl.ezVnxI > div > div > button.sc-gsDKAQ.jiHobE",)
  elem.click()

except:
  print("No button found")
```